# Adding html spans into a LabelFor - MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've got a complicated form, which needs to be used by both javascript and non-javascript users.  My application is .NET MVC 3.

The form has plenty of fields, which have to be filled in if they answer a particular way to a previous question.  With javascript enabled, I'm able to show or hide the relevant question based on a user interaction.  With no javascript I would like to add more detail to the question label itself because by default all of the questions are shown (much like filling in a paper version of the form).

Ideally I would like the label to be something like:

```
<label><span class="non-js">If you were a smoker, when</span><span class="js">When</span> did you stop smoking?</label>
```

This way I can switch off the relevant text in CSS (I'm hoping a screenreader can cope with this).

So javascript users get:

```
When did you stop smoking?
```

and non-javascript users get:

```
If you were a smoker, when did you stop smoking?
```

My question is how would I go about doing this, as LabelFor helpers don't allow html in the string.

**Update**

Sorry, I forgot one crucial bit of info, in that my label is currently being populated by a  [Display(Name = "When did you stop smoking?")] annotation in the model.  Idelly I would like to keep this here and have something like:

```
[Display(JS = "When", NonJS = "If you were a smoker, when", Both="did you stop smoking?")]
```

Is this possible?

**Update 2**

OK here's what I've got so far.  This is my attribute:

```
public class MultipleDisplayNameAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
    public string CustomerDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerJSAlternative { get; set; }
    public string CustomerNonJSAlternative { get; set; }

    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        string jsPart;
        string nonJsPart;
        jsPart = (CustomerJSAlternative != null) ? String.Format("<span class='spnJs'>{0}</span>", CustomerJSAlternative) : "";
        nonJsPart = (CustomerNonJSAlternative != null) ? String.Format("<span class='spnNonJs'>{0}</span>", CustomerNonJSAlternative) : "";
        metadata.DisplayName = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", jsPart, nonJsPart, CustomerDisplayName);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I'm now stuck as this is displayed unencoded on the screen. i.e. it is actually coming out like this on screen:

```
<span class="non-js">If you were a smoker, when</span><span class="js">When</span> did you stop smoking?
```

Is there any way to change the displayName metadata property to cope with this?

**Update 3 and solution**

With the help of the answers and http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/07/03/asp-net-mvc-labelfor-helper-with-htmlattributes.aspx I managed to get the solutions I was after:

My attribute:

```
public class MultipleDisplayNameAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
    public string CustomerDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerJSAlternative { get; set; }
    public string CustomerNonJSAlternative { get; set; }

    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.AdditionalValues["JS"] = (CustomerJSAlternative != null) ? String.Format("<span class='spnJs'>{0}</span>", CustomerJSAlternative) : "";
        metadata.AdditionalValues["NoJS"] = (CustomerNonJSAlternative != null) ? String.Format("<span class='spnNonJs'>{0}</span>", CustomerNonJSAlternative) : "";
        metadata.DisplayName = CustomerDisplayName;
    }
}
```

My helper:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString JsAndNonJsCheckFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
        HtmlString jsLabel = new HtmlString("");
        HtmlString noJsLabel = new HtmlString("");
        string htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

        string labelText = metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(labelText))
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;


        if(metadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("JS"))
            jsLabel = new HtmlString((string)metadata.AdditionalValues["JS"]);


        if (metadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("NoJS"))
            noJsLabel = new HtmlString((string)metadata.AdditionalValues["NoJS"]);

        TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("label");
        tagBuilder.Attributes.Add("for", html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(htmlFieldName));
        tagBuilder.InnerHtml = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", jsLabel, noJsLabel, labelText);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
```

Job done (eventually!)  Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Hey @Sniffer, did you take a look at my answer?  Is there anything extra you need?

Comment: Hi @Millimetric unfortunately I'd missed a crucial part of the question out. Can you see the 'update' section above? Sorry about that.

Comment: That *would* be possible, all you'd be missing is writing a custom `Attribute`, and getting the data from that in your `LabelFor` function.  (Ideally getting it populated in `ModelMetaData`, although reflection is an option.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current problem is just how `LabelFor` works.  This is the decompiled source code for `LabelFor` (from MVC2. The actual source is probably nicer, and is freely available for download):

```
    public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
      return LabelExtensions.LabelHelper((HtmlHelper) html, ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<TModel, TValue>(expression, html.ViewData), ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText((LambdaExpression) expression));
    }

    internal static MvcHtmlString LabelHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, string htmlFieldName)
    {
      string str = metadata.DisplayName;
      if (str == null)
      {
        string propertyName = metadata.PropertyName;
        if (propertyName == null)
          str = Enumerable.Last<string>((IEnumerable<string>) htmlFieldName.Split(new char[1]
          {
            '.'
          }));
        else
          str = propertyName;
      }
      string innerText = str;
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(innerText))
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
      TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("label");
      tagBuilder.Attributes.Add("for", html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(htmlFieldName));
      tagBuilder.SetInnerText(innerText);
      return tagBuilder.ToMvcHtmlString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
    }
  }
```

You could basically copy this code, change the method name, and change the second last line of code to be:

```
tagBuilder.InnerHtml(innerText);
```

And it you will have a working solution which doesn't escape your HTML.

Comment: Thanks - this got me on the right track.  Just to note - it's InnerHtml, not SetInnerHtml.  Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

You can write your own LabelFor extension to Html.  I would recommend this since you could pass in the js and non-js text as parameters instead of having to write the HTML over and over again.  Here's the basic Label type helper:

```
using System;
namespace MvcApplication1.Helpers
{
      public class LabelHelper
      {
           public static string LabelJsNonJs(this HtmlHelper helper, string target, string nonJs, string js, string commonText)
           {
                return String.Format("<label for='{0}'><span class='non-js'>{1}</span><span class='js'>{2}</span>{3}</label>", target, nonJs, js, commonText);
           }
      }
}
```

You can use this in your views by adding a using for your MvcApplication1.Helpers namespace.

See http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/07/03/asp-net-mvc-labelfor-helper-with-htmlattributes.aspx for more info on making a LabelFor type helper (a little more complicated and I don't have much time).