# DisplayName text via LabelFor without encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there an elegant way to output the text in a model property's DisplayName attribute using LabelFor without encoding? The DisplayName attribute contains an *em* tag that need to rendered as raw HTML.

I'd like to avoid creating a custom helper unless it is unavoidable. If it's unavoidable please describe how to create a helper that can override LabelFor.

Property in the model:

```
[DisplayName("Title <em>&lt;title&gt;</em>")]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

Razor view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but it seems there is no way of doing this like this post with original helper source code is showing:

[Adding html spans into a LabelFor - MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823816/adding-html-spans-into-a-labelfor-mvc-3)

Seems like you have to implement your own helper.